# How to associate contact with last campaign upon Lead conversion via Campaign

Tags: campaign, campaign-member, conversion

I have a question around Lead conversion, which is associated with multiple campaigns.The goal is to associate the converted contact with the latest campaign sent out to the Lead. We are not using Opportunity Object, so, is there any standard way to implement this or I shall go ahead with some customization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce does this out of the box. You might not see it on your page layout, so head over to Setup > Customize > Contacts > Page Layout(s), and add the Campaign Related List to the layout. However, it doesn't just copy the latest campaign, but all campaigns the lead may be associated to, and it will also automatically merge any duplicate entries. See [Considerations for Converting Leads](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=leads_notes.htm&type=0).

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for responding. Which means in order to get this capability on Lead conversion I have to manage via apex trigger on campaign member?

Comment: @Monika The contact is automatically associated with the campaign. What additional logic are you trying to implement?

Comment: As Initially said - 1 lead could be attached to multiple Campaigns, now at the time of conversion of Lead I would want the latest associated camapign to be part of Converted Lead-Contact.  It is easier if we have opportunity object, but in my case we are not using opportunities, we will be counting the success of contact conversion rate

Comment: @Monika It already is part of the Contact. You don't need an Opportunity to get the Lead conversion data to the Campaign. Have you taken a look at the Campaign Related List on the contacts, and tried converting a Lead?